# Результат в одну строчку сгруппировать и разбить по тэгам

Tags: php, xml

Есть код:

```
<?php echo $yml->replaceSpecial($this->renderPosition('image')); ?>
```

Есть результат одной строкой:

```
<image>site.com/image/img-1 site.com/image/img-2 site.com/image/img-3</image>
```

Как разбить его по тэгам чтобы конечная строчка приобретала вид:

```
<image>site.com/image/img-1</image>
<image>site.com/image/img-2</image>
<image>site.com/image/img-3</image>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью регулярных выражений:

```
$string = '<image>site.com/image/img-1 site.com/image/img-2 site.com/image/img-3</image>';

$pattern = ['~<(image)>([^<]+)</\1>~', '~(?<=\b|\s)(\S+)(?=\s|\b)~'];
$replace = ['$2', '<image>$1</image><br />'];

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: @I.Z. если не нужен перевод на новую строку, то уберите тег **<br />** из второго шаблона `<image>$1</image>` **<br />**

Comment: Супер! Убрал <br />. И получилось то, что и нужно было получить! Эдуард - огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Самый примитивный подход для данной строки

```
<image>site.com/image/img-1 site.com/image/img-2 site.com/image/img-3</image>
```

будет использование функции [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php) с заменой пробела на строку

```
"</image>\n<image>"
```

Comment: а можно было strip_tags применить .... а еще explode нужен и формирование новых строк с image

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `конечная строчкА приобретала вид:` ;)

Comment: а, понял замысел

Comment: Ребят, Спасибо за комментарии и участие!

Answer (score 2):

С начало убираем теги `image` из строки методом `str_replace`.
Потом разбиваем строку по пробелам и получаем массив.

Это код:

```
<?php

    $str1 = '<image>site.com/image/img-1 site.com/image/img-2 site.com/image/img-3</image>';
    $str1 = str_replace("<image>", "", $str1);
    $str1 = str_replace("</image>", "", $str1);

    $arr = explode(' ', $str1);
    $finish_str = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($arr);$i++){
        $arr[$i] = '<image>'.$arr[$i].'</image>';
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

А это то что получаем:

```
Array
(
    [0] => site.com/image/img-1
    [1] => site.com/image/img-2
    [2] => site.com/image/img-3
)
```

Comment: Razmik, спасибо большое, это работает. Без обид, но за решения я выберу результат Эдуарда. Всем кто будет искать подобное решение также советую воспользоваться этим методом. Спасибо!